# SP Designer 2013 to use for a specific site collection not for whole web application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I want to use SharePoint designer but as we know by using it we have an access to the whole web application.Is it possible to use SP Designer2013 for only one(single )site collection?Is it possible to lock other site collections ?
If then how?

Please help 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As a site collection administrator, you can specify for each site collection if SPD should be enabled or not from the site collection administration page in each site collection.

```
/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx
```

So if you really have to enable SPD for just one site collection, i would use PowerShell to loop through all the site collection and disable SDP and then enable it for the single site collection where you need to use the designer.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$webapp = get-spwebapplication http://yourwebapplication

foreach ($site in $webapp.sites)
{
    $site.AllowDesigner = $false
}
```

And then you can set the single site that you wanna use.

```
$site = get-spsite http://yoursitecollection

$site.AllowDesigner = $true
```

**Update**

To re-enable SPD on all the site collections again, simple just run the first script again but change `$false` to `$true`

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$webapp = get-spwebapplication http://yourwebapplication

foreach ($site in $webapp.sites)
{
    $site.AllowDesigner = $true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christoffer.As I am unaware of powershell scripts can you please share the code to again enable SPD for all site collections.

Comment: I updated my answer, just a switch. :)

Comment: Thanks Christoffer.I ran the scripts but still I am able to access the contents of the other site collections too? Do I need to update something on site collection through script  OR on web app?

Comment: Are you site collection administrator for all of the site collections? Are you trying to use SPD as a standard user against a site collection where SPD is disabled? Check through the UI to make sure that one of the site collections are disabled for SDP to make sure that the change went through. I'm unable to access the sites i have set to not allow SPD with the designer.

Comment: 1.yes,I am site collection admin of all site collections
2.Yes,tried using SPD as a standard user where SPD is disabled but as a standard user I can't access the remote machine .
My requirement is I want something that  for that particular site collection disabled the site contents  should not  be available in SPD.
can u please tell what kind of users can use SPD(like read,contribute,full control,admin etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can manage how Microsoft SharePoint Designer is used at two levels:

- Web application level which is applicable to all site collections in
  the web application and to the site collection administrators.
- Site collection level (managed by site collection administrators)
  which is applicable to all sites in the collection along with the
  Designers and Owners group.

Note:

> In SharePoint, only the **Designers group** **and above** can open SharePoint
>   sites in SharePoint Designer 2010.

As Chris Mentioned the Powershell, alternatively you can use the Site settings and Disable it.

Once you disabled it at web app then nobody can use the designer even Site collection administrator. But if you enable at Web app level and try to disable on site collections level then anyother Site collection admin can enable it again.

Another Approach is, it cause more overhead on server, if you move the site collection( which required Designer access) into own web app then disable it on other web apps. But it is expensive in term of server resources.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2592376